# Как отправить свой контакт боту через библиотеку telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, share

Есть код, но кнопка не появляется:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton

def contact(update, context):
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_phone = KeyboardButton(text="Отправить телефон", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(button_phone)
    update.message.reply_text('Отправьте номер телефона', reply_markup=keyboard)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token=API_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", contact))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить функцию contact на:

```
def contact(update, context):

    contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Отправить номер', request_contact=True)
    custom_keyboard = [[contact_keyboard]]
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)

    update.message.reply_text('''*Отправьте номер*''', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)
```